# Infinspan cache is not geting refreshed in jboss eap 6.3

Tags: jmx, infinispan, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to refresh an infinispan cache using jmx programmatically.
I am using jboss eap 6.3 and infinispan 5.2.
I could stop and start the cache instance on the server (logs in the server console showed '11:37:41,693 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (pool-1-thread-4) JBAS010282: Stopped ServiceRegistry-cache cache from ServiceRegistryCache container
11:38:09,953 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (pool-1-thread-4) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
11:38:09,954 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (pool-1-thread-4) JBAS010281: Started ServiceRegistry-cache cache from ServiceRegistryCache container'), but still the cache didnt get refreshed. I am getting the old values itslef. My code is shown below.

```
String urlString = System.getProperty("jmx.service.url","service:jmx:remoting-jmx://" + host + ":" + port);
JMXDemo demo = new JMXDemo();
System.out.println(demo.testJMX(urlString));
String username = "abc";
String password = "abc#123";
HashMap env = new HashMap();
String[] creds = new String[2];
creds[0] = username;
creds[1] = password;
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
JMXConnector jmxConnector;
jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, env);
MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.infinispan:type=Cache,name=\"ServiceRegistry-cache(local)\",manager=\"ServiceRegistryCache\",component=Cache");
connection.invoke(objectName, "clear", null, null);
connection.invoke(objectName, "stop", null, null);
connection.invoke(objectName, "start", null, null);
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Are you attempting to clear the cache? There are simpler ways for that, like invoking clear(). Infinispan is clustered by default, is it possible a second node is running in the same network, and so your data is being replicated and so surviving the restart?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to clear the cache. I have invoked clear method but it didn't worked (the values were taken from the cache itself)  that's why I tried to stop and start the cache.

Comment: And CacheMode was also set to LOCAL.